# Do pact archetype wizards have full curse progression?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, class, character-levels, curses

I'm pretty sure that I can't be reading this right, but the pact wizard archetype from 5th level says you gain an oracle curse and you count your oracle level as half your wizard level. Looking up the oracle's curses it says that the curse has a level equal to your oracle level plus 1/2 your level in any other classes. To me this means that at say 10th level you count your oracle level as 5th, no problem there, but the description under the curse suggests that you have 10  class levels which would give an additional 5 curse levels. Did they really mean for the pact wizard to get full curse progression? I can't find anything about it.

Curses do apparently progress without level of oracle, was this just supposed to indicate a more serious advance than just a 1 level dip in oracle could expect?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6):

The extraordinary ability **great power, great expense** of the wizard archetype [pact wizard](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/pact-wizard-wizard-archetype/) says, in part, "At 5th level, the pact wizard chooses one oracle curse, using 1/2 his character level as his effective oracle level **when determining the effects of this curse**" (emphasis mine). Half the pact wizard's level isn't the pact wizard's effective oracle level for *all* purposes, though. Instead, half the pact wizard's level is used *only* for determining the effects of the picked curse. For example, when a pact wizard that possesses the curse [**aboleth**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Aboleth) is level 10 she adds the spell *minor image* to her spellbook  and to her spells known, and at level 20 she adds the spell *modify memory* to her spellbook and spells known.

To be clear, while the extraordinary ability [oracle's curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Base-classes/Oracle/#Oracles_Curse_Ex) of the base class oracle says, "An oracle’s curse is based on her oracle level plus one for every two levels or Hit Dice other than oracle," a pact wizard doesn't actually have *that* ability; the pact wizard gained her curse from the ability great power, great expense. So the pact wizard doesn't benefit from the ability oracle's curse like a *real* oracle would. (No offense, pact wizards.)

Comment: To be clear, what’s being said here is that getting “one oracle curse” isn’t the same as getting “oracle’s curse.” Which I agree, is what the rules say, but boy oh boy do I think there’s lots of critique to go around here, both for the oracle’s authors and the pact wizard’s. Great power, great expense sure reads to me like the author forgot oracles use half their non-oracle levels by default...

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, renaming the oracle class feature from **oracle's curse** to, like, **exposed to greatness** or pretty much *anything* besides oracle's curse would probably reduce the chance it'd be confused with **oracle curses**. Bleah. (By extension, it bugs me that some classes have a class feature named **spells**; as each class follows its own rules for spells, the **spells** class feature should have a specific and unique name, like **wizard spells** or whatever.)

Comment: And then there’s hide in plain sight...

Comment: @KRyan O, God, yes. The list is long and horrible. I kind of want to blame the *3.5* revision, though. I can't be sure, but I think the overlap—except for the class feature spells—was vastly less (and not just because there was less content) prior to the revision. Afterward, though? It's all, like, "Thesaurus? Is that CR 3?"